# Does homomorphic image imply surjection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

My question is what the phrase "homomorphic image" means exactly, and the specific example that I am looking at is to prove: If $G$ is the homomorphic image of $\mathbb{Z}$, then all homomorphic images of $G$ are cyclic.

I'm not asking for a proof, but when I started to prove it, I introduced an arbitrary group $H$ and let $\varphi : G \to H$ be a homomorphism, and my goal is to prove that $\varphi(G)$ is cyclic.

But in my lecture notes, my professor assumed additionally that $\varphi$ is a surjection. I don't understand why we are allowed to suppose this, unless that is what homomorphic image implies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\phi:G\to H$ is a homomorphism, we call $\phi(G)$ a homomorphic image of $G$. A function is always surjective onto it’s image. So by replacing $H$ with the image $\phi(G)\subset H$ we can simply assume $\phi$ to be surjective.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. So, if we went through the gory details, either $\varphi$ is surjective or it is not. If it is not, then restrict the codomain from $H$ to $\varphi(G)$, and proceed with a proof. Since the proof is similar in either case, it suffices to assume that $\varphi$ is surjective. Is that right?

Comment: Somewhat, yes. One might take $H$ as a homomorphic image of $G$ instead of an arbitrary group, then $H = \phi(G)$.